# Render a large set of features in the map and make them interactive

Tags: postgis, geoserver

We have a lot of different features (points,lines,polygons) saved in the PostgreSQL with PostGIS.

And we have to display these data in a map (we use OpenLayers 2.13 at the moment), and the different features are organized as a tree, user can check the features they are interested.

There is no problem once user the features selected by user have only a little records, we can add them in the map directly.

However when user select too many features or one feature contains too many records, it is impossible to display them all once, although we only search features inside the map extent, but think about once the map is zoomed at a small zoom level.

So we tried to use geoserver to render the map at the server side, but we need the feature rendered in the map clickable, that's to say once a feature is displayed in the map, user can click it, then we will show the detail information about this feature. But we meet two problems:

1 The features are overlapped one by another.
For a given point feature layer, there maybe some points nearby each other(the distance between them are very close), so when zooom to small level, these features will overlap with each other.

2 Make them clickabe.
I know there is a `WMSGetFeature` in OpenLayers, but since the data are served by different wms service, so it is not a good idea.

And I have thought to request the features for the user selected feature types, and then instead of rendering them in the map, we calculate once the mouse inside the bounding of the feature, if yes, we display the feature. I am not sure if this is acceptable.

Also I have another idea, do not use wms at all, just search the data inside the viewport of the map, but we will limit the returned count of the features, and them render them with OpenLayers API.

I want to know if you guys have meet this kind of requirement, and how do you make it.

Answer (score 1):

To render effectively a large set of map features in a web mapping environment, the dataset should be tiled and/or generalized as described in [this document](http://www.researchgate.net/publication/264244246). WFS cannot help since it is for data download rather than for on-the-fly visualisation. You should use a server able to share vector tile pyramids (not geoserver) and a client able to render it (leaflet or openlayer).

Comment: That's right when handle real large data set like the rivers,roads, which compose the basic of the map, we generate tiles too. However the data I mentioned here are not as large as it sounds, some of them are uploaded by the user, so pre-tile them is not possible.

Comment: And also, even tiled, the feature in the map are static which means they are not interactive.